# How to verify a function is a solution to a PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Given the PDE $u_t + uu_x = 0$, where $u(x, 0) = f(x)$, I need to verify that $u=f(x-tu)$ is a solution to the PDE. How does one do this?

Of course, intuitively one understands that substitution would be the first method to try. So, $u_t = -f_t(x-ut)(u+tu_t)$, $u_x = f_x(x-ut)(1-tu_x)$. Thus $u_t+uu_x=-f_t(x-ut)(u+tu_t)+uf_x(x-ut)(1-tu_x)=-f_t(x-ut)(f(x-ut)+tu_t)+f(x-ut)f_x(x-ut)(1-u_x)$.

Now, if $t=0$, we get: $-f_t(x)f(x)+f(x)f_x(x)(1-u_x)$.

So, how does one verify that the above reduces to zero? I'm lost.

Also, I'm wondering that if $u=f(x-ut)$, does this mean that $u$ is defined in terms of itself? How can that be?

Answer (score 1):

You forcing function $f$ is a function of $1$ variable, so there should be no $f_t$ or $f_x$; just $f'$. The chain rule gives $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x-tu) = f'(x-tu) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} [x-tu] = f'(x-tu)\cdot[-u  - tu_t].$$ Likewise $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-tu) = f'(x-tu) \cdot [1 - tu_x]$$ Then for $u$ satisfying $u = f(x-tu)$, we have \begin{align*} u_t + uu_x &= f'(x-tu)\cdot[-u-tu_t] + f'(x-tu) \cdot [u - tu u_x] \\
&= -t f'(x-tu)\cdot[u_t + u u_x].
\end{align*} So either $u_t + uu_x = 0$ or $f'(x-tu) = -1/t$, but the latter isn't possible because $f'(y)$ needs to actually needs to actually depend on $y$; i.e., any definition of $f'(x-tu)$ should include the quantity $x-tu$.

Comment: If the function $f$ depends on $x-tu$, then why is it a function of one variable?

Comment: Also, why does $f'(x-tu)$ have to be $-1/t$? Why not $f'(x-tu)=0$? Moreover, if we have that $u_t+uu_x = 0$, doesn't this automatically imply that the result equals zero? Again, though, we're having a strange recursion here.

Comment: If $f'(x-tu) = 0$ then we are done because we have $u_t = u_x = 0$. Otherwise to satisfy the equation above becomes $$(u_t + uu_x)( 1-tf'(x -ut)) = 0$$ which implies that either $u_t + uu_x = 0$ or $1 - tf'(x-tu) = 0$, the latter is impossible so we conclude that $u_t + uu_x = 0$.

Comment: Here $f$ is a map $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ so $f$ takes in a single value and gives out a value. For example, we could have $f(x) = \sin(x)$. This is as opposed to something like $g(x,t)$ which takes in two values and gives a single value. This is why it is impossible that $1 - tf'(x-tu) = 0$ for all $x,t$. Consider the example $f(x) = \sin(x)$. Then $f'(x-tu) = \cos(x-tu)$. Do you see why we cannot have $$1 - t \cos(x-tu) = 0$$ for all $x,t$ regardless of what $u(x,t)$ is?

Comment: Where is $(1-tf'(x-ut))$ coming from? It's $-tf'(x-tu)$ in your original result. Do you mean that we can divide the resulting equation in your answer by $[u_t+uu_x]$ to get $1 = -tf'(x-tu) \iff 1+tf'(x-tu)=0 \iff f'(x-tu) = -1/t$?

Comment: I can see that $t \le tcos(x-tu) \le t$. But if we had a function of two variables, would we be able to make the above term equal to $0$ for all $x$, $t$? @User8128

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. You verify a PDE the same way you verify that a number is a solution to an equation: You plug it into the equation and show that both sides are equal.

So you're on the right track. I think you'll make it if you're a little more careful in your computation. Toward that end, I have two questions for you. First, what is "$f_t$"? Second, what is "$f_x$"? ($f$ is a function of only one variable.)

---

User8128 points out --- In nonlinear PDEs, implicit definitions like $u=f(x-tu)$ are often the best we can do. If we insist on certain properties of $f$, we can ensure that $z = f(x-tz)$ has a unique solution for all $x,t$ in some set. On that set, we define $u(x,t) = z$ to be the unique solution to the equation. (I add: I would guess that this may also help in numerically solving the equation.)

Comment: Implicit definitions like $u = f(x-tu)$ are alright are alright; often is the best we can do for a non-linear PDE. Given certain properties of $f$, we can usually ensure that the equation $z = f(x-tz)$ has a unique solution for all $x,t$ in some special set. On that set, we define $u(x,t)$ to be the unique solution to the equation.

Comment: @User8128 Thanks for the background; mind if I incorporate that into the answer?

Comment: @Neal: $f_t$ means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$.

Comment: No, I don't mind at all.

Comment: @sequence The point of asking is, that doesn't actually make sense :P